# Read properties file from local machine using javascript/jquery/angular js/angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

We have a properties file in local machine (for example, c:/foo/foo.properties).

How to read that properties file to get the content in it using javascript, jquery and angular?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: The solution would be to find a very old version of javascript. But nowadays what you ask may be impossible.

Comment: Only possible on user action using FileApi (https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). Otherwise would be a huge security hole.

Comment: Can we select a file automatically with file api. For example, var file = new File('c:/foo/foo.properties');.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0):

> Please provide a solution to read it, only using javascript, jquery
>   and angular.
>
> It's an urgent requirement.

The answer is: It's an impossible mission. There is no way for you to read a file on a computer using Javascript or anything of its frameworks or libraries, except one: which is NodeJS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please provide me the sample with NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a local file using client side script due to security issue you have to use some server-side script like node.js,php etc for that to work.